# Stacktrace errors from previous save after updating Primefaces .xhtml files

Tags: tomcat, jsf, netbeans, facelets

In my project I use Java EJB + Primefaces with Tomcat 7.11. Editor is NetBeans.
My project worked fine until I accidentaly moved some .xhtml files to another folder and saved. After moving the files back to the correct location "MyProject\web\templates",
now no matter what I do, the Tomcat stacktrace produces following error:

```
06-Apr-2020 15:35:17.522 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [my/project]threw exception
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Facelet /templates/navbar.xhtml not found at: file:/C:/path/to/java/MyProject/build/web/templates/navbar.xhtml
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory._createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:387)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$000(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:57)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:124)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCacheImpl.getFacelet(FaceletCacheImpl.java:84)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCacheImpl.getFacelet(FaceletCacheImpl.java:51)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:278)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:574)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:553)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:228)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:55)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:374)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:50)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:195)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:521)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:575)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:553)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:151)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:189)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:477)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:78)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:267)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at ..
```

My question is What causes this and why?

Comment: I corrected your tags.

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by deleting NetBeans cache, but it still remains a mystery why this happens. I tried to reproduce it by doing the exact same thing (moving some .xhtml files to different path and saving) with no luck.

Quickest way to remove NetBeans cache is by applying the following command to CMD runned as ADMIN:

```
del /s /q %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\
```